# Adicionar CSS inline na imagem usando Tiny MCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

Estou usando [Tiny MCE](https://www.tinymce.com) para o cliente postar em um site que estou desenvolvendo. Funciona super bem, o problema é que quando se posta uma imagem no Tiny MCE, e altera o tamanho dela, ele gera a seguinte linha:

```
<img src="source/imagem.jpg?14641" alt="" width="550" height="838">
```

E com isso a imagem não fica responsiva, o que precisaria era que o Tiny MCE colocasse umm css inline na imagem, para ficar assim:

```
<img src="source/imagem.jpg?14641" alt="" width="550" height="838" style="
    width: 100%; max-width: 550px; height: auto;">
```

Alguém sabe se é possível?

Comment: Você só pode adicionar o css inline? Ou pode fazer também num arquivo externo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No TinyMCE.ini adicione o seguinte código:

```
image_dimensions: false,
         image_class_list: [
            {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-responsive'}
        ]
```

Você também pode tentar utilizar alguns plugins extras dele como:

http://tinymceplugins.com/plugins/responsive-filemanager

http://tinymceplugins.com/plugins/tinymce-bootstrap-tools

Comment: Interessante. Mas a única questão é que eu não consigo dar uma medida mínima para a foto né? 
Depois é só colocar max-width: 100% na classe?

Comment: ~vc pode tentar colocar 'img-responsive' e uma outra tag sua de css. mas acho que só essa tag do bootstrap caso esteja utilizando resolve.

Comment: Boa, não estou usando bootstrap, mas resolveu! Só depois criar essa classe.

Comment: é que quase todo mundo utiliza o bootstrap fiz pensando nele, mas vc pode ou utilizar ou fazer a classe que desejar.